# I am getting error for calculating cells in excel using python but i dont know why?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is the code
:

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = "C:/Users/jains/Downloads/Python/Python/SA.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_name) 

df['Sum'] = df['data']*df['petha']+df['leta']*df['deta']


df.to_excel("C:/Users/jains/Downloads/Python/Python/SA.xlsx")
```

this is excel file
[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCdak.png)

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jains\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'leta'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jains/Downloads/Python/Python/SCreatefile2.py", line 5, in <module>
    df['Sum'] = df['data']*df['petha']*df['leta']*df['deta']
  File "C:\Users\jains\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3455, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\jains\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'leta'
```

why?this error.I cant understand why the error is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted there is a KeyError: 'leta'. Make sure you are writing the column name correctly.

- check if there is a space in the column name

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. something wrong in the "leta" column name.

Comment: Ok sir Let me check

Comment: Sorry sir for wasting ur time @Murtada Altarouti.Due to my mistake in the excel sheet there was 1 space after 'a'.Sorry sir

Comment: Sorry @ozs sir.